# bootstrap - centering multiple columns of various widths

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get 5 different bootstrap columns of varying widths centered on the page.  I'm sure it's possible especially with the new flex/grid stuff, but I must be missing something.  Here is an image from the FF inspector of the issue.
[image]

The issue is that right spot in the blue.  It is obviously longer than the left side in the blue.  Everything else looks to be symmetrical.

And here is my Bootstrap HTML creating the layout.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="copyDateText" class="row col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 mx-auto text-center">
  <div class="col-sm-auto">
    About Us
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-auto">
    Site Map
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-auto">
    View our Privacy & Terms
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-auto">
    Security
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-auto">
    <span style="vertical-align:top;">&copy;2005-$date.get('yyyy') Company, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the `col-sm-8 offset-sm-2`.  But i'm not sure how to get that content centered otherwise.

Comment: Adding justify-content-center to #copyDateText will center your items. http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: Always use `.row > .col > .row > .col` not `.row > .row.col > .col`

Comment: add class="d-flex justify-content-center" to your row col-sm-8 element

Comment: @ZimSystem thanks for the tip, learned something new.

Comment: @FurkanPoyraz and @helloworld thanks, that does the trick, it appears I don't even need the `.d-flex`

Comment: In the inspector, I see that class `row` already has the display property set to flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it can be easily corrected by flex box, working example is attached below, just copy and paste it in an .html file and you are good to go

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This is the program written to flatten the array using Javascript and HTML5 -->
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="copyDateText" class="col-sm-8 d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto offset-sm-2 row text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                About Us
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                Site Map
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                View our Privacy & Terms
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                Security
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                <span style="vertical-align:top;">&copy;2005-$date.get('yyyy') Company, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

as you can see, I just added two classes **d-flex** and **justify-content-center**, it will do the trick, and if you have any further questions then let me know.

Comment: Thanks Samar, that does the trick.  It appears that I don't even need the `d-flex` class.

Answer (score 0):

Add another row inside the #copyDateText div and then use margin: auto on that row.

Your HTML will look like this (might need to go full-width to see the entire menu):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div id="copyDateText" class="row col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 mx-auto text-center">
    <div class="row" style="margin:auto;">
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        About Us
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        Site Map
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        View our Privacy & Terms
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        Security
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <span style="vertical-align:top;">&copy;2005-$date.get('yyyy') Company, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, add the inline CSS to your stylesheet afterwards.